# How to add tags via channel form?

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I am trying to allow for tags being added to an entry submitted via a channel form, but right now submissions end in an error message about the Language field being required (that's the tag field) even though I did enter a tag.

I am also wondering if it is possible to strip out the "suggest tags" and "top tags" buttons from the way the tag input appears in a channel form when using "{field:tag_fieldtype_name}"?

The form looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="channel9" return="Links" class="Submit" id="Submit"}
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" size="50" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();" />

    {custom_fields}
        <label for="{field_name}">{field_label}</label>
        {if textarea}
            <textarea id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" dir="{text_direction}" cols="50" rows="{rows}" onclick="setFieldName(this.name)">{field_data}</textarea>
        {/if}
        {if textinput}
            <input type="text" dir="{text_direction}" id="{field_name}" name="{field_name}" value="{field_data}" maxlength="{maxlength}" size="50" onclick="setFieldName(this.name)" />
        {/if}
    {/custom_fields}

    {field:9_language}  

    {category_menu}
        <label for="categories">Categories</label>
        <select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4">
            {select_options}
        </select>
    {/category_menu}

    {if captcha}
        <br />
        <label for="captcha">Please enter the word you see in the image below:</label>
        <br />
        {captcha}
        <br /><br />
        <input type="text" name="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" maxlength="20">
    {/if}

    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
{/exp:channel:form}
```

The generated html looks like this:

```
<h3>Submission Form</h3>

<form id="Submit" class="Submit" method="post" action="http://www.westeros.org/Links/Submit"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class='hiddenFields'>
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://www.westeros.org/Links/Submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="URI" value="Links/Submit" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="Links" />
<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="channel_id" value="9" />
<input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="19" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta" value="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" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="Links" />
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="91d57eea93d5db7b27df4e73b48072e4f2d8edad" />
</div>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" size="50" maxlength="100" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();" />
<label for="9_url">URL</label>


<input type="text" dir="ltr" id="9_url" name="9_url" value="" maxlength="100" size="50" onclick="setFieldName(this.name)" /><label for="9_description">Description</label>

<textarea id="9_description" name="9_description" dir="ltr" cols="50" rows="10" onclick="setFieldName(this.name)"></textarea><label for="9_language">Language</label>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.westeros.org/Scripts/ExpressionEngine/themes/third_party/tag/js/jquery.tag_autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" href="http://www.westeros.org/Scripts/ExpressionEngine/themes/third_party/tag/css/tag.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.westeros.org/Scripts/ExpressionEngine/themes/third_party/tag/js/tag.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" href="http://www.westeros.org/Scripts/ExpressionEngine/themes/third_party/tag/css/front_base.css" />
<!--[if IE 8]><div class="solspace_tag_group ie8" id="solspace_tag_field_206"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><div class="solspace_tag_group ie9" id="solspace_tag_field_206"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<div class="solspace_tag_group" id="solspace_tag_field_206">
<!--<![endif]-->
    <textarea style="display:none;" id="solspace_tag_ta_206"
              name="9_language"></textarea>

    <div class="solspace_tag_new_tags">
        <div class="tag_section_name">
            <div class="staticwrap">
                <span class="add"></span>
                Add&nbsp;Tags           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag_section_data">
                <div class="solspace_tag_input_area">
                <div class="tag_error_dialog">
                    <span class="notice">Error text</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="tag_input" value="" class="tag_input"/>
                            <div class="suggest_tags white_grad">
                    <span class="glass"></span>
                    <span class="tag_button_label">Suggest&nbsp;Tags</span>
                </div>
                <div class="top_tags white_grad">
                    <span class="star"></span>
                    <span class="tag_button_label">Top&nbsp;Tags</span>
                </div>
                        </div>
            <div class="tag_clear"></div>
            <div class="solspace_tag_current_tags">
                                <div class="tag_clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag_clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="solspace_tag_suggest_tags">
        <span class="tag_section_closer ex"></span>
        <div class="tag_section_name">
            <div class="staticwrap">
                <span class="glass"></span>
                Suggest&nbsp;Tags           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag_section_data">
            <div class="refresh_suggest_tags white_grad">
                <span class="refresh"></span>
                <span class="loading"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="tag_clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag_clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="solspace_tag_top_tags">
        <span class="tag_section_closer ex"></span>
        <div class="tag_section_name">
            <div class="staticwrap">
                <span class="star"></span>
                Top&nbsp;Tags           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag_section_data">
                            <div class="top_tag white_grad" data-tag="S2">
                    <span class="tag_count">762</span>
                    <span class="plus"></span>
                    <span class="tag_name">S2</span>
                </div>
                            <div class="top_tag white_grad" data-tag="Previews">
                    <span class="tag_count">686</span>
                    <span class="plus"></span>
                    <span class="tag_name">Previews</span>
                </div>
                            <div class="top_tag white_grad" data-tag="Game of Thrones">
                    <span class="tag_count">526</span>
                    <span class="plus"></span>
                    <span class="tag_name">Game of Thrones</span>
                </div>
                            <div class="top_tag white_grad" data-tag="WorldCon">
                    <span class="tag_count">485</span>
                    <span class="plus"></span>
                    <span class="tag_name">WorldCon</span>
                </div>
                            <div class="top_tag white_grad" data-tag="Season 3">
                    <span class="tag_count">459</span>
                    <span class="plus"></span>
                    <span class="tag_name">Season 3</span>
                </div>
                        <div class="tag_clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tag_clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(global){

        //defaults and tag sets for the external JS
        var data = global.solspaceTag           = global.solspaceTag || {};

        //global items (ok to overwrite)

        //secureFormHash
        data.secureFormHash                     = '91d57eea93d5db7b27df4e73b48072e4f2d8edad';
        //this might be localized to fields later
        data.tagLimit                           = '0';

        data.langItems                          = {
            'error'                     : "Error",
            'tag_limit_reached'         : "Tag Limit of %num% reached.",
            'explode_separator_desc'    : "Error"
        };

        data.tabName                            = '';
        data.delimiters                         = {"colon":":","comma":",","doublepipe":"||","newline":"\n","pipe":"|","semicolon":";","space":" ","tab":"\t","tilde":"~"};

        //per field items

        //current tags
        data['currentTags']                     = data['currentTags'] || {};
        data['currentTags']['206']  = [];
        //top tags
        data['topTags']                         = data['topTags'] || {};
        data['topTags']['206']      = ['S2','Previews','Game of Thrones','WorldCon','Season 3'];
        //all open
        data['allOpen']                         = data['allOpen'] || {};
        data['allOpen']['206']      = 'no';
        //xids
        data['xids']                            = data['xids'] || {};
        data['xids']['206']         = '91d57eea93d5db7b27df4e73b48072e4f2d8edad';
        //auto complete
        data['autocompleteURL']                 = data['autocompleteURL'] || {};
        data['autocompleteURL']['206']= 'http://www.westeros.org/?ACT=59&method=tag_autocomplete&tag_separator=doublepipe&tag_group_id=1';
        //suggest tags
        data['suggestTagsURL']                  = data['suggestTagsURL'] || {};
        data['suggestTagsURL']['206']= 'http://www.westeros.org/?ACT=59&method=tag_suggest&tag_separator=doublepipe&tag_group_id=1';
        //suggest fields
        data['suggestFields']                   = data['suggestFields'] || {};
        data['suggestFields']['206'] = [];
        //EXPLOOOOOOODDDEE!
        data['explodeSeparator']                = data['explodeSeparator'] || {};
        data['explodeSeparator']['206'] = false;
        //separator
        data['separator']                       = data['separator'] || {};
        data['separator']['206']        = '\n';

        //if people load these via ajax, we need to set the events
        if (typeof  global.solspaceTag.domReadyFired !== 'undefined' &&
                    global.solspaceTag.domReadyFired == true)
        {
            global.solspaceTag.setFieldEvents("#solspace_tag_field_206");
        }
    })(window);
</script>

<label for="categories">Category</label>
<select name="category[]" id="categories" size="4">
<option value='170'>A Song of Ice and Fire Fan Sites</option>

<option value='174'>Fan Artists</option>

<option value='209'>Game of Thrones Fan Sites</option>

<option value='171'>George R.R. Martin Fan Sites</option>

<option value='221'>Official Sites</option>

<option value='172'>Professional Artists</option>

</select>


<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">// <![CDATA[ 
if (typeof EE == "undefined" || ! EE) { 
var EE = {"publish":{"title_focus":true,"smileys":true,"url_title_prefix":"","default_entry_title":""},"user_id":1,"lang":{"confirm_exit":"When you leave, any data entered will be lost. Are you sure you want to leave?","add_new_html_button":"Add New HTML button"},"XID":"91d57eea93d5db7b27df4e73b48072e4f2d8edad","CSRF_TOKEN":"91d57eea93d5db7b27df4e73b48072e4f2d8edad"};}
EE.grid_cache = [];

window.Grid = {
    bind: function() {
        EE.grid_cache.push(arguments);
    }
};mySettings = {"nameSpace":"html","onShiftEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"replaceWith":"<br \/>\n"},"onCtrlEnter":{"keepDefault":false,"openWith":"\n<p>","closeWith":"<\/p>\n"},"markupSet":[{"name":"b","key":"B","openWith":"<strong>","closeWith":"<\/strong>","className":"btn_b"},{"name":"i","key":"I","openWith":"<em>","closeWith":"<\/em>","className":"btn_i"},{"name":"blockquote","key":"Q","openWith":"<blockquote>","closeWith":"<\/blockquote>","className":"btn_blockquote"},{"name":"a","key":"A","openWith":"<a href=\"[![Link:!:http:\/\/]!]\"(!( title=\"[![Title]!]\")!)>","closeWith":"<\/a>","className":"btn_a"}]};

 // ]]>
</script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://www.westeros.org/?ACT=52&ui=core,widget,mouse,position,draggable,resizable,button,dialog,datepicker&plugin=markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay,tmpl&file=underscore,cp/date&v=1405860060&use_live_url=y&include_jquery=y"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SafeCracker = {}; SafeCracker.markItUpFields = EE.markItUpFields = {};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat:"d-m-y"+EE.date_obj_time});
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({defaultDate: new Date(1422970896000)});
});
// ]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">.hasDatepicker{background:#fff url(http://www.westeros.org/Scripts/ExpressionEngine/themes/cp_themes/default/images/calendar_bg.gif) no-repeat 98% 2px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:99%;}</style>
```

Comment: Please post generated HTML to inspect. I suspect you might have duplicate fields in your form. Additionally, inspect browser's javascript console for any errors.

Comment: I added the generated HTML to the main post. I am not familiar with how to use the javascript console - where would I find that on Seamonkey?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if 'Allow EE Code' can apply to a channel form but it works for CP side fields... https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [Tag documentation for use in the EE Channel Form](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/using_with_channel_form/). The `{custom_fields}` tag pair might not work: try using the field as in the example in the documentation: `{field:tag_fieldtype_name}`.

To hide the "suggest tags"/"top tags" sections, you can do so using javascript of (even better) CSS.

Comment: Actually, I am using the second method here: {field:9_language} is the tag field. I tried it with the {custom_fields} pair too, no luck with that either.

Answer (score 0):

You have this tag fields displayed 2 times: one time inside *{custom_fields}* pair and another one when you call it by name.

You may filter the first one by changing *{if textarea}* to

> {if textarea AND field_name != "9_language"}

Comment: If I make that change, submitting the form leads to the following message: This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.

Comment: If you did not change anything but that line, then the error is irrelevant and the form is really expired. Please double check.